# Transformations that are not orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Are there transformations that will preserve angles but are not orthogonal? Intuitively it seems like this should be true (i.e. we can have a transformation preserve angles without being orthogonal), but I'm having trouble coming up with any concrete examples. Are there classes of transformations that have this property?

Comment: homothetic transformations are not orthogonal.

Comment: I assume that you're asking about linear transformations of a finite dimensional vector space and you have a fixed inner product in mind?

Comment: For me, orthogonal only applies to **linear** maps.  If you are asking about more general transformations, then you want **conformal** maps.  (Although these are orthogonal when you linearize them.)

Answer (score 1):

Take the transformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ with $T(x)=2x$. This simply scales vectors by $2$, so does not change the angles, but is not orthogonal, since its standard matrix is $2I$.